# Is there a streaming endpoint for DNS lookup / IP metadata?

Tags: dns, streaming, dig, nslookup

I would like to know all changes of domain names / metadata linked to a given (wide) range of IPs.
For now, I execute a batch of scripts that extract regularly the domain name / metadata behind each IP inside a given range through dig commands.

Instead of a such batch / 'query', is there a way to 'listen' all new changes (among a range of IPs at least) instead? Notably an event stream endpoint or command?
A bit like the following Wikimedia's endpoint that notify from all new changes: https://stream.wikimedia.org/v2/stream/recentchange

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What IP addresses, yours or others? If it's others, then please tell us you IP address endpoint so we can block it.